# accessing x number of same structs in another struct

Tags: c, linux, pointers, memory, struct

I want to create a program which uses the poll feature of linux. I'm trying to achieve a few structs containing a number of polls as well as a pointer to each poll. Setting the number of polls is no problem, however setting the pointer to each poll is a problem.

In calloc, mem returns a pointer to memory, but I wanted to use mem[0] like a pointer to a chunk of memory to contain the first poll struct and mem[1] like a pointer to a chunk for the next poll struct etc.

`struct pollfd` is already defined in poll.h that was included with my linux package, so I don't need to redefine it in my program.

How do I reserve memory spaces for individual poll structs with allocating a total of only one segment of memory instead of one segment per struct?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>

typedef struct{
    long numpolls;
    struct pollfd* poll;
}mainrec;

int main(void){
    struct pollfd** mem=calloc(1,sizeof(struct pollfd)*10000);
    printf("alloc %d\n",sizeof(struct pollfd)*10000);
    mainrec* rec[10];

    rec[0]->numpolls=2;
    rec[0]->poll=mem[0];
    rec[0]->poll[0].fd=2;
    rec[0]->poll[1].fd=3;

    rec[1]->numpolls=1;
    rec[1]->poll=mem[1];
    rec[1]->poll[0].fd=2;

    free(mem);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
// Allocate an array of 10 pollfds
struct pollfd *mem = calloc(10,sizeof(struct pollfd));
// Get an array of 10 mainrecs
mainrec rec[10];

// Populate the first element of mainrec with two polls
rec[0].numpolls=2;
rec[0].poll=mem+0; // points to the first pollfd and the following...
rec[0].poll[0].fd = ...;
rec[0].poll[0].events = ...;
rec[0].poll[0].revents = ...;
rec[0].poll[1].fd = ...;
rec[0].poll[1].events = ...;
rec[0].poll[1].revents = ...;

// populate the second element of mainrec with a single poll
rec[1].numpolls=1;
rec[1].poll=mem+2; // points to the third pollfd
rec[1].poll[0].fd = ...;
rec[1].poll[0].events = ...;
rec[1].poll[0].revents = ...;
```